# Usage of joins: getting the oppsite result

Tags: sql

I am working with oracle and below I have a basic sql query where I select the schools that have a team using a `join`. However I am struggling how can I select the opposite(schools that don’t have a team) using a join as well. I tried using the words `outter`, `inner`, `left` and `right` but to no avail I get the results that I desired. How can I list the schools that don’t have a team?

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.school_name, a.school_id, b.school_id FROM School a RIGHT OUTER JOIN Team b ON a.school_id = b.school_id;
```

Results:

```
SCHOOL_NAME               SCHOOL_ID  SCHOOL_ID
------------------------- ---------- ----------
Panthers University          92022      92022
Blue Rays Middle School      22149      22149
```

Tables:

```
schools

 SCHOOL_ID SCHOOL_NAME                   SCHOOL_TYPE
---------- ----------------------------- ------------
     92022 Panthers University           University
     22149 Blue Rays Middle School       Middle SchooL
     21719 Bull Dogs High School         High SchooL
     42736 Saint Lucia Grade School      Middle SchooL

school_teams

   TEAM_ID   SPORT_ID  SCHOOL_ID TEAM_NAME
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1      92022  Panthers
         2          1      22149 Blue Rays
```

Comment: I am seeing in your above  result, You are displaying the school have the team id.  Please use the left join with the null condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those joins (inner, outer, left, right) select only rows that match.  You are looking for rows that DON'T match, so they won't suit you.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT school_id, school_name FROM school 
  WHERE school_id not in
    (SELECT school_id FROM school_teams)
```

Comment: Probably the easiest to understand solution for someone not that comfortable with SQL but I do think people should get there head around the NOT EXISTS solution as this handles composite keys etc

Comment: Thanks, @ClintGood.  NOT EXISTS is new to me. It looks like for non-null ID's, there's no difference -- but all the same, from now on I think I'll be using NOT EXISTS instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Not exists` to do this.

```
SELECT a.school_name, a.school_id 
FROM School a 
where not exists (select 1 from Team b where a.school_id = b.school_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.school_name, a.school_id, b.school_id FROM School a LEFT OUTER JOIN Team b ON a.school_id = b.school_id;
```

Comment: This will select all schools -- with or without teams.  OP wants only schools with NO teams.

Answer (score 0):

Write this query to generate the required result set. Use **Left** Join.

```
SELECT Table1.School_Name, Table1.School_Id FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.School_Id = Table2.School_Id where  Table1.School_Id NOT IN (Select DISTINCT Table2.School_Id From Table2);
```